# Kendo UI Grid cell as image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a kendo grid in asp net mvc web app to display the currently online users.

[image: img1]

I use a custom command to get the green symbol on the grid:

```
column.Command(command =>
    {
        command.Custom("img").Text("<img src='~/Content/Icons/bullet_ball_glass_green.png' />");
    }).Width(48);
```

I tried to use a template (and ClientTemplate) to use just the image:

```
column.Template(@<img src='~/Content/Icons/bullet_ball_glass_green.png' />).Title("Estado").Width(65);
```

But this approach does not load the image to the cell, it leaves it blank.

[image: img2]

**Is there a way to get only the image in the cell?** I don't like using a command to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
  .ClientTemplate("<img src='" + @Url.Content("~/Icons/") + "bullet_ball_glass_green.png'/>")
```

Comment: Why does it work using the `@Url.Content`? I'm intrigued by that.. It serves the purpose, thank you.

Comment: I bet it is a path issue. If you console.log (@Url.Content ()) you can see the content root.